# How to make a radio button deselected by default in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2, radio-button

Can somebody please tell me how to set the default value of radio buttons blank and then get the value from client whatever user selects and accordingly update the table.

I am using following code snippet but seems to be something wrong in it :

```
        var blnValue4 = false;
        for (var i=0; i < document.forms[0].chkTeam.length; i++)
        {

            if (document.forms[0].chkTeam[i].checked)
              blnValue4 = document.forms[0].chkTeam[i].value;
               return blnValue4;

        }

        if(blnValue4 = false)
        {
            alert("Please answer question in  team participation.");
            document.getElementById("chkTeam").focus();
            return false;

        }
```

and then this is how i assign default values :

```
<td colspan =2>
:<html:radio  property="chkTeam" value=""  />Yes
<html:radio   property="chkTeam" value="" />No

                </td>
```

Note that in form it is set to accept Boolean as return type.

Comment: `<html:radio>` is not struts2, it is struts1.

Comment: My mistake sorry for typo

Comment: it's definitely wrong as off requires code to format for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Please I can't understand your question, deselect or unselect. this one is make different, like unselected mean's not choose the value, deselected mean's particular person or part should disqualified. following codes are general for like ognl and list, As these are following as:

But, create a radio button via OGNL expression and preselect the “2″ as the default value.

```
<s:radio label="Answer" name="yourAnswer" list="#{'1':'Yes','2':'No'}"value="2"/>
```

It will generate the following HTML code…

```
<input type="radio" name="yourAnswer" id="resultAction_yourAnswer1" value="1"/>
<label for="resultAction_yourAnswer1">Yes</label> 

<input type="radio" name="yourAnswer" id="resultAction_yourAnswer2" 
checked="checked" value="2"/>
<label for="resultAction_yourAnswer2">No</label>
```

In Java code, create a List to return the values for the radio button.

```
List<String> genders = new ArrayList<String>();
        genders.add("male");
        genders.add("female");
        genders.add("unknown");
    public List<String> getGenders() {
        return genders;
    }
    public String getDefaultGenderValue(){
        return "unknown";
    }
```

In result page,  tag, the list=”genders” will call the getGenders() method to return a list of the keys and values for the radio button. And the value=”defaultGenderValue” will call the getDefaultGenderValue() method to preselect the “unknown” value as a default value for the radio button.

```
<s:radio label="Gender" name="yourGender" list="genders" value="defaultGenderValue" />
```

It will generate the following HTML code…

```
<input type="radio" name="yourGender" id="resultAction_yourGendermale" value="male"/>
<label for="resultAction_yourGendermale">male</label> 

<input type="radio" name="yourGender" id="resultAction_yourGenderfemale" value="female"/>
<label for="resultAction_yourGenderfemale">female</label> 

<input type="radio" name="yourGender" id="resultAction_yourGenderunknown" 
   checked="checked" value="unknown"/>
<label for="resultAction_yourGenderunknown">unknown</label>
```

Comment: +1 for the effort, but if you don't understand a question (as stated in your answer's first sentence), ask clarification in comments *before* writing the answer, so you would be able to write a shorter, more targeted one, in less time ;)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i have figured out the answer.

Comment: Actually i was looking on how can i  make a radio button mandatory in struts meaning none of the radios should be checked by default and when user traverses the page and when he reached that radio he should get the alert box as to please select either of the radio and once selected capture the input in db and move to next page. Hope i made it clear....thanks alot people for helping.....